# Comparing object silhouette with a 3d representation

Tags: rendertexture

I'm working on a game where a user can draw the outline of an object, I use it to create a mask texture and I want to compare this outline with a 3d object.
The solution I come up with is to render object to texture and compare two textures pixel by pixel.
So my question is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What specifically do you find unsatisfactory about your current approach, that answers should focus on improving?

Comment: Well, it's not that I have anything in particular, I thought that this task was solved already but I just couldn't google it. My approach is not wrong but seems very "naive".

Comment: Try the naïve way first. If it works, it works. 